# Quiver representation - definition clarification

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quiver

I'm studying quiver representation on "Introduction to representation theory" by Etingof and others. Often I read on this book about a representation being injective or surjective at some vertex (of a quiver) i.

**What does precisely mean, for a quiver representation, to be injective (surjective) at some vertex?**

Is this relate to the direct sum of the functions corresponding to the arrows pointing in and out of i?

Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

From the context, I'm pretty sure that what is meant is:

If $i$ is a source vertex of the quiver $Q$, then a representation $V$ of $Q$ "is injective at $i$" if the obvious map
$$V(i)\to\bigoplus_{i\to j}V(j)$$
is injective, where the direct sum is indexed by all arrows starting at $i$.

And "surjective at $i$" is the dual notion for a sink vertex.